# Spring not map date in miliseconds to POJO when GET request

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

I have request that is sending date parameter in miliseconds like that:

```
http://localhost:8090/advanced-search-for-publications?fromPublicationDate=11111111
```

and bean like this:

```
public class AdvancedSearchForPublicationsRequest {

    private Date fromPublicationDate;

    public Date getFromPublicationDate() {
        return fromPublicationDate;
    }

    public void setFromPublicationDate(Date fromPublicationDate) {
        this.fromPublicationDate = fromPublicationDate;
    }
}
```

and Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "advanced-search-for-publications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Response<PublicationsSearchResult> advancedSearchForPublications(AdvancedSearchForPublicationsRequest request) {
    System.out.println(request.getFromPublicationDate());

    //TODO change it
    return null;
}
```

But program is printing null. What could I make to make this mapping works?

Comment: Shouldn't you use @RequestParam to bind your variable to the request?

Comment: Binding complex object should work too. Did you try with other types like String or Integer? Maybe there is a problem with Date conversions.